# Resources to study Nyström methods and their error analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, numerical-calculus, finite-difference-methods

I'm working on a problem that states that:

The Nyström methods have the form:

$$u_{n+r} = u_{n+r-2} + \Delta t \sum_{j=0}^{r}\beta_h f(u_{n+j}).$$

**The problem is:** Find the two step explicit and implicit Nyström methods and determine their errors.

I did a quick search on Nyström methods but apart from [Wikipidea,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nystr%C3%B6m_method) I coudln't find any beginner's resources on it. Could you please cite me a resource where they detail these and the error analysis as well?